# How to write unit test for file upload class in django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http-post

I am trying to write unit test for a class which is having a POST method for uploading documents to web based django application. Here is my view class for which I want to write unit test:

```
class SOP(APIView):
authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
def post(self,request):
    returnDict={}
    returnDict['msg']='File not uploaded'
    #if form.is_valid():        
    newdoc = Document(sopFile = request.FILES['sopFile'])
    newdoc.save()

    returnDict['msg']='File uploaded'
    returnDict['fileName']=newdoc.sopFile.name
    # Redirect to the document list after POST
    return Response(returnDict)
```

As my django application is using forms.py for uploading a file so I am putting that code also along with this:

```
from django import forms
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
docfile = forms.FileField(
    label='Select a file',
    help_text='max. 42 megabytes'
)
```

I have tried to write test case using RequestFactory() and TestCase() but I am not able to figure how to write unit test for this type of class/views...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#module-django.test.client) from Django. It's very easy to use.

Example from Django docs:

```
>>> c = Client()
>>> with open('wishlist.doc') as fp:
...     c.post('/customers/wishes/', {'name': 'fred', 'attachment': fp})
```

Comment: then I think I am doing something else wrong.. my terminal shows me that "Test label 'lib.SOPTestCase.testWithRequestFactory' does not refer to a test"... BTW thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You could try mocking what you need with something like [this](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html).

Comment: I'm confused by this, could you give an example of how you'd mock this out? Thanks!